# How do I change directory & rename the file during uploading in nodeJs?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, multer

**I am using multer and fs to upload an image file**
*How do I change the directory of uploaded file,since all files are stored my "routes" folder rather than "uploads" created by multer*
Also,how can i change name file EXAMPLE :

> username.jpg

this is my code:

```
var upload = multer({ dest: '/tmp' });

router.post('/file_upload', upload.single("file"), function (req, res) {
    var file = __dirname + "/" + req.file.originalname;
    fs.readFile(req.file.path, function (err, data) {
        fs.writeFile(file, data, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                res.redirect("back");
            }

        });
    });
})
```

**On client Side:**

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>File Uploading Form</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h3>File Upload:</h3>
        Select a file to upload:
        <br />
        <form action="/file_upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-
    data">
            <input type="file" name="file" />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it as follows, unless you need to keep the uploaded file in its original upload location:

```
var upload = multer({ dest: '/tmp' });

router.post('/file_upload', upload.single('file'), function (req, res) {
    // Here change 'uploads' to the folder name you prefer.
    // Also change req.file.originalname for your preferred file name
    var file = path.join(__dirname, 'uploads', req.file.originalname)
    fs.rename(req.file.path, file, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.redirect("back")
        }

    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare your directory in storage variable

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './')//Declare it here where you want to store
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname);//You can give name here file.****
    }
});
var upload = multer({
    storage: storage
});
```

while handling post request

```
var path = req.files[0].path;
    var imageName = req.files[0].originalname;//change name here
    var imagepath = {};
    imagepath['path'] = path;
    imagepath['originalname'] = imageName; // name change
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't your variable **file** specifying where you are writing to your file?

```
var file = __dirname + "/NewFolder/" + newFileName.jpg
```